# How to add labels to each bar in the barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data `df`:

```
   type     operation  year    month    weekday
1  A1       AAAA       2011    11       Tue
2  A1       BBBB       2011    11       Mon
3  D3       AAAA       2012     1       Tue
4  A1       AAAA       2012     1       Thu
5  D3       DDDD       2012    11       Thu
6  D3       BBBB       2013     1       Wed
```

Then I need to group this data by `type` and `operation` and calculate the number of occurances of each combination. I am currently grouping `df` as follows:

```
grouped_data = aggregate(df,
                 list(type_names = df$type,
                      operation = df$operation),
                 FUN = function(x){NROW(x)})
```

Then I plot it using grouped barchart:

```
ggplot(grouped_data, aes(type_names,type)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = operation), position = "dodge", stat="identity")+
  coord_flip()
```

My question is how to add additional labels to bars? In particular I store some additional information about each `type` in a separate data frame called `add_data`. Let's say this is the popularity index (`pop_ind`) of each type.
How can I attach `pop_ind` values to each corresponding bar?

Comment: you would add `geom_text(data = add_data, aes(label = pop_ind))` assuming you as the same `type_names` value in `add_data` for aligning your x-values

Comment: @NathanDay: I tried this approach. The `add_data` contains two columns `type_names` and `pop_ind`. The only thing is that `add_data` contains more types than `grouped_data`. I get the error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'type_names' not found`. I don't understand why it cannot find the object `type_names`...

Comment: Why don't you merge the 2 dataframes before plotting, at least for the labelling column ?

Comment: Could you provide us a dataset to suggest you solutions ?

Comment: that error is likely from you specifying `x = type_names` outside of `aes`, but it's impossible to telll/help until we see `dput(add_data)`. PS `dput()` is a better way to add example data to you questions as opposed to text tables

Comment: @FiofanS, If you have tried that approach you _need_ to include that in the question and explain what is going wrong.